# Python bisection search confusion

Tags: python

I'm trying to work on the MIT intro to CS with Python problem set 1.

Here's the problem (bottom of page 3):
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf

Here's my code:

```
#best savings rate in 3 years

annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
total_cost = 1000000
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
portion_down_payment = 0.25*total_cost
r = 0.04

low = 0
high = 10000
pre_saved = int((high+low)/2)
steps = 0
current_savings = 0
epsilon = 100


months = 0
salary_increase_months = 0
portion_saved = pre_saved/10000
print(portion_saved)
while abs(current_savings - portion_down_payment) >= epsilon:

    #calculates savings after 36 months
    while(months < 36):
        #checks every 6th iteration to add the semi annual raise
        if(salary_increase_months == 6):
            annual_salary += annual_salary*semi_annual_raise
            salary_increase_months = 0
        current_savings += current_savings*(r/12) + portion_saved*(annual_salary/12)
        salary_increase_months += 1
        months += 1
        #print(current_savings)

    #bisection search portion
    if current_savings < portion_down_payment - epsilon:
        #print('1')
        low = portion_saved*10000
        current_savings = 0
    elif current_savings > portion_down_payment + epsilon:
        #print('2')
        high = portion_saved*10000
        current_savings = 0

    elif current_savings < portion_down_payment + epsilon and current_savings > portion_down_payment - epsilon:
        print('Best savings rate:', portion_saved)
        print('Steps in bisection search:', steps)
        break
    else:
        print('It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years.')
        break
    portion_saved = int((low + high)/2)
    portion_saved = portion_saved/10000
    steps += 1
    months = 0
    salary_increase_months = 0
```

When I put in a value for the salary, all I get is the original percentage saved (0.5) and the output doesn't end. Nothing else gets printed. I created three if statements that are supposed to check the value of portion saved and do a bisection search (if the value is higher than portion down payment plus epsilon, then high becomes the portion saved, and vice versa).

Comment: Your `while months < 36:` loop only works right on the first iteration of the outer `while` loop - on subsequent iterations, `months` is 36 already.  You have a similar problem with `salary_increase_months` - it only equals 6 one time, since you never reset it.

Comment: I added two new lines that reset the number of months and salary increase months. I still get the same issue.

Comment: I never reset the annual salary in addition to the other values mentioned before. That was the problem. I think it's working now.

Comment: So the problem I'm dealing with now is when the current savings can never reach the portion down payment value. I thought the else statement covered that scenario, but what happens is that it's stuck in in infinite loop of searching for the best savings_rate. What is the best way to fix this problem? Do I use the number of steps to determine if getting enough savings is impossible? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def curr_saving(salary, Semi_raise, saveP, month):
saving = 0
monthly_income = salary/12
# down_pay = 0.25*cost
for i in range(1, month):
    if i % 6 == 0:
        salary += salary*Semi_raise
        monthly_income = salary/12
    interest = saving*(1+0.04/12)
    saving = monthly_income*saveP+interest
return saving

def Hunting_C(base, Semi_raise, cost):
    # saving = 0
    # salary = base
    # monthly_income = salary/12
    down_pay = 0.25*cost
    No_month = 36
    # saving_range = numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.0001)
    step = 0
    min_S = 0
    max_S = 1
    saveP = (min_S+max_S)/2
    while (abs(curr_saving(base, Semi_raise, saveP, No_month)-down_pay)) >= 100:
        step += 1
        if curr_saving(base, Semi_raise, saveP, No_month) > down_pay:
            max_S = saveP
        else:
            min_S = saveP
        saveP = (min_S+max_S)/2

    return f'saving rate: {saveP}, No of steps: {step}, current saving: {curr_saving(base, Semi_raise, saveP, No_month)}'


print(Hunting_C(150000, 0.07, 1000000))
```

Comment: Posting code without any explanation isn't that helpful and discouraged on Stack Overflow because it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5698098) to improve your post's quality. See also [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for reference.

Comment: The detailed explanation of the steps needed in the code is provided in the problem set section C posted by the jp207 that asked the question. I think that's enough. I can always add few more words if needed. 
                                                                           
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf

Comment: It's best when answers (and questions) are independent of external resources; otherwise important context is missing when these resources become unavailable (which happens all the time). (Of course, it's great to include them as references). Also to clarify, including an explanation for the code means to explain how it answers OP's question(s). While this code may be a complete solution it doesn't explain what the OP did wrong in his posted code, or how he can fix his particular problem(s).